# A2Billing Extension using DID even after I remove it?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I have installed A2B but facing some problem while using DID. I configured DID and assigned to to one Extension but the Extension still using the DID even after I remove the DID.

I am not using that DID in sip.conf to define 'fromuser' but it seems something hardcoded and by default using the DID.

Is there anyone out there can suggest me the way to address this issue or put some light on it?

Answer (score 0):

Last patched a2billing version for sure will not work if any of following not true:

1) User exists and ACTIVE, activated time not in future

2) Did exists, active, creation date not in future and not empty

3) did_destination have record for destination.

So you have done it not via a2billing or have all above TRUE.

Comment: 1) User exists and ACTIVE, activated time not in future

2) Did exists, active, creation date not in future and not empty

3) did_destination have record for destination.

Comment: Ignore the above comment please.. 


1) User exists and ACTIVE, activated time not in future - User still exist and Active but no DID assigned. Calls that route internally only work for this user. Can't receive any call routed via SIP Trunk.

2) Did exists, active, creation date not in future and not empty - I only switched the User but the DID still exist since I wanted to use it for another user so kept the record but it's not in use.

3) did_destination have record for destination - When remove the CID & CALLER ID from the extension I also removed the record from did_destination.

Comment: If you switched it to other user, that other user is ACTIVE and you have SAME destination - it will work, yes. You have change destination for new user.

Comment: But the problem is, that old Extension (user) still showing that DID as Caller ID. I am not sure if this one happening from the end of the TRUNK provide of there's some issue inside my system.

Comment: Finally found the reason and managed to resolve it.
The option in Dashboard actually not RELOADING Aster properly. I did it from inside CLI.
Also, the TRUNK provider had some issue but they did not informed me. After they resolve it from their end they notified it with the list of updates.

Now, everything working just fine.